# Reverse and HttpResponseRedirect don't work with DefaultRouter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I need to send back response with product details, so I use HttpResponseRedirect and reverse. It requires the app_name:name, so I tried something like below, but I get error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'product' not found. 'ProductViewSet' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

This is my view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def bump(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=pk)
    product.bumps.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('products:product', args=[pk]))
```

This is my urls:

```
app_name = 'products'
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', ProductViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls), name='product'),
]
```

What is wrong in this code? I use the correct app_name and name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is wrong in this code? I use the correct `app_name` and `name`.

The path you use does not link to a view: it is a path that contains a lot of subpaths, all generated by the `DefaultRouter`.

You are using a router, this means that it will create different paths that will each have a specific name. These are documented [in the documentation for the **`DefaultRouter`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter).

You thus can visit this with:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def bump(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    product.bumps.add(request.user)
    return redirect('products:product-detail', pk)
```